# Executing series of SQL commands on the command line

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, batch-file, database-backups

I want to run a series of SQL statements against a SQL Server 2005 database from the command line.

When I launch 1st statement

```
osql -E -S <Server_Name>\<Instance_Name> -d <Server_Name>
```

it is going to prompt window `1>` from there after I am unable to proceed further through script.

How to give input to `1>` prompt I mean giving next SQL statement

```
BACKUP DATABASE  TO DISK = 'c:\test.bak' WITH INIT,SKIP
```

and finally `exit` to that prompt

I tried with && but I guess that is for only commandline commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ae looking for the -Q switch on the sqlcmd tool (don't use osql on sqlserver 2005 or higher) (type sqlcmd /? to see all options) or lookit up on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

```
sqlcmd -E -S <Server_Name>\<Instance_Name> -d <Server_Name> -Q "BACKUP DATABASE TO DISK = 'c:\test.bak' WITH INIT,SKIP"
```

Alternatively you can create a sqlscript file where you put all the sql statements in you want to execute. Assuming you name your file myscript.sql the osql command would go like this:

```
 sqlcmd -E -S <Server_Name>\<Instance_Name> -d <Server_Name> -i myscript.sql
```

Comment: Also: as of SQL Server **2005** - you should use `sqlcmd` instead of `osql`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may want to try a small trick that emerged from other question in this forum (that was deleted unfortunately).

You may insert the input for a command directly in the lines below the command and then execute the file NOT as Batch file, but as input por cmd.exe (this is similar to a *here document* in Linux). For example:

script.TXT:

```
@echo off
osql -E -S <Server_Name>\<Instance_Name> -d <Server_Name>
BACKUP DATABASE  TO DISK = 'c:\test.bak' WITH INIT,SKIP
exit
```

Execute previous "script" this way:

```
cmd < script.TXT
```

If you perform this test, please report the result...

Antonio

Comment: Thanks for reply but it did not help me... because again i am using some batch commands in script.txt what u suggested...

Comment: You may execute previous script.TXT file inside your normal Batch file, that is, in your Batch file include `cmd < script.TXT` line and put in script.TXT just the commands for OSQL... This way you may even dinamically create the .TXT file in the Batch file with selected (not fixed) commands! (interesting idea, isn't it?)